# Get error: "Password is required for managed user" when authenticating user with ADAL Library

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, adal, wia

Try to run the project of [active-directory-dotnet-native-headless](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless), it works when acquiring token with username password. But failed and throw exception when acquiring token with Windows Integrated auth(WIA) as below:

```
            //UserCredential uc = TextualPrompt();
            // if you want to use Windows integrated auth, comment the line above and uncomment the one below
            UserCredential uc = new UserCredential();
            try
            {
                result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientId, uc).Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                ShowError(ee);
                return;
            }
```

The error is:

> An unexpected error occurred. Message: One or more errors occurred.
>   Inner Exception : password_required_for_managed_user: Password is
>   required for managed user

The PC to run the program has joined AD, the user to run the program is also domain user. OS is windows 10.

Is there any further configuration need to be done on AAD to make it work?

Comment: You can't mix and match. Windows integrated authentication will never work for cloud (Azure AD). The fact that you are on a AD joined computer does not change the situation much. Azure AD only talks modern protocols - OpenID Connect,  OAuth, not so m8dern - ws-federation and to some extend SAML. None of them is compatible with kerberos/ntlm, without additional work. Use app wothout windows integrated and find appropriate sample to work on.

Answer (score 1):

You get this strange exception for a "managed" user when doing an Integrated Windows Auth (IWA) flow. Managed users are those created in AAD without an AD backing. IWA is based on an old protocol that works by calling some apis on the AD server. Since there is no AD server, we can't enable this flow.

I've updated the error messages on ADAL and MSAL and added details to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario can work if you use AAD Connect (so your on-premises AD users are synced to AAD) and enable Seamless SSO on your tenant.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso

Answer (score 0):

If you replace this line

```
result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientId, uc).Result;
```

with this one

```
result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientId, new Uri("http://TodoListClient-Headless"), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)).Result;
```

everything should work fine (in my [scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54713158/azure-ad-active-domain-seamless-sign-on/) this was the solution).