# Azure AD, Active Domain & Seamless Sign On

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, seamless-login

My aim is to acquire silently an Azure AD token from a Domain joined workstation whose domain is connected to Azure AD through Azure AD Connect.
In order to do that I've built the following scenario:

- I configured a **Windows Server** and an **Active Domain** on it
- I connected the **Active Domain** to **Azure AD** using **Azure AD
  Connect**
- I configured the **Seamless Sign-On**: in fact, if I
  use a web-browser from a domain joined machine to navigate to the url
  https://myapps.microsoft.com/my_azure_domain.onmicrosoft.com I'm
  **logged in** correctly **without user interaction**
- If I use [this example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless/tree/master) in order to **obtain** an **Azure** AD JWT
  **Token** **interactively** from a domain joined workstation (using the Textual Prompt) everything    works **fine**
- If I use the same example in order to **obtain**
  an **Azure** AD JWT **Token** **silently** from a domain joined workstation (using the
  Windows-integrated security -    UserCredential) I obtain the
  following **error**:

> Inner Exception : password_required_for_managed_user: Password is
>   required for managed user

What am I missing?
Thanks,
Daniele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by replacing this code (lines 152 and 212 of [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless/blob/master/TodoListClient/Program.cs) file)

```
authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientId, uc)
```

with this one

```
authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientId, new Uri("http://TodoListClient-Headless"), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)).Result
```